# Are there any philosophical implications to slow light?

Tags: time, light, relativity

I know this is a question and I am not forming any arguments to my question. I am just after some further information.

I know the application of slow light can have use in the communication industry as light can go slower in some mediums than in vacuum.

But are there any philosopical implications of this phenomena?

Comment: Even light can be slow.  That makes me feel better philosophically speaking.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Lol I have the same feeling

Comment: As other's have said, the speed of light through different media being different doesn't impinge on any philosophical issues AFAIK. However, it is interesting to ponder what, if anything, would be different if c=3e12 m/s or c=1000 m/s. But that is a question for Physics SE :)

Comment: @Annika OK, but if c = 0 meters per second, I think we would have a problem.

Comment: :) agreed - but that  may be one of those edge cases that results in some kind of discontinuity somewhere.

Comment: @Annika No worries :-)

Comment: Bob Shaw's [light of other days](https://wiki2.org/en/Light_of_Other_Days) says yes. This is a wikipedia link. If you like short SciFo find a copy and read it rather than this page which summarises it.

Comment: Note also that there are materials and arrangements in which light can exceed C; nevertheless it seems there are no implications either for physics, nor for philosophy. If you have concerns, state them in the question.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the information :-)

Comment: surely lack of a global reference frame particularly for simultaneity as inferred/dictated? by a limit on the speed of light has philosophical implications

Comment: I wonder why there are so many views?... is it something more to this?

Comment: @IoannisPaizis Is philosophy absolute?

Comment: never, that's why I am squeezing my mind about this.

Comment: @IoannisPaizis As long as you don't squeeze your soul out of your mind in practice lol...

Answer (score 5):

Prior to Einstein, there wouldn't have been any reason to see philosophical implications of the speed of light, any more than philosophical implications of the fact that the speed of <del>cars</del> horse carriages slows down on a busy afternoon.

With special relativity, it is suggestive to think this would change. But it doesn't, really, because the relevant speed-of-light constant does *not* change. Indeed, for subatomic processes the water-slowing does not take action.

All that actually happens is that specifically *visible-light photons* interact with the water molecules in such a way that their effective movement (in particular, the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity)) is slowed down, so they don't in fact move at the speed of light anymore.

An intuitive description is to say that the photons are briefly absorbed by the molecules, before being emitted again with a very slight delay (≈attosecond).

It so happens that this interaction affects not only visible light but also lower-frequency radiation, and in the Maxwell equations this is described by the materal-dependent permittivity term. But all that is only a macroscopic approximation, not a feature of the fundamental physical laws; therefore I would indeed agree [with niels nielsen](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/104681/22296) that it has no philosophical implications even with relativity.

Comment: IMO there's a small misconception here, the value we all know as the speed of light is actually it's speed in a vacuum, not any special "default value", it means that when slowed by another medium, it still goes at the speed of light, for this medium (which is constant too). Saying "don't in fact move at the speed of light anymore" is kind of taking the problem upside down ;) For the question I would say it had actually important consequences, because it leads to the decomposition of white light by a prism which was an interesting question historically (did greeks have an explanation?)

Comment: @Kaddath I phrased it deliberately this way. The vacuum speed of light _is_ **the** speed of light, or the "default value". Other media don't really have a different speed of light (though that is often said), they only have different phase- and group velocities. Arguably "speed of light" is a misnomer entirely, and only makes sense from a historical perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are philsophical implications to it, like for any other concept. I don't see why the speed of light in different media should be an exception.

As an example, forms of life (like fishes, let's assume) which live in mediums in which light travels differently than it does for humans would have a different aesthetic perception of visual objects because of slow light. That would have aesthetical, psychological, social, economical, political (the list goes on...) ripercussions.

Comment: well .. state some!

Comment: No offence but I dont think fish barter between one another for food , and I don't think  there is politics within fish society. However I'm human and not a fish.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 Borrowing from Nagel, we don't know what it's like to be a fish.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 no offense taken. Here is a paper regarding decision making (an area traditionally equated to politics) in fish environments: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780128053089000282)

Comment: @AndreaNerla Point taken fish are alive and you can speculate that they exhibit behavior based upon the experience an knowledge of there environment a big fish would be incharge of a small fish and there may be some politics there. But would that be a cause of the way  it perceives its environment? I would think its political environment would be independent of the medium that it lives in :-)

Comment: As a big proponent of the Butterfly Effect theory, I would say yes. It's just an area on which research hasn't been done yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit of a stretch but the only thing that comes to mind is the impact on causality.  Based on the theory of relativity, cause and effect is limited by the speed of light.  When the rate at which a signal can be transmitted is reduced, the size of the associated [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) is reduced as well.

This doesn't seem to have any meaningful implications in normal human experience, but I suppose it might relate to interpretations and tests of [non-locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_nonlocality) in quantum mechanics.